# How to loop through a date range in Python query string and append results to a dataframe/csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pymysql

I'm connecting to a mysql database in python using pymysql.
I want to run a query for each day in a date range and append the results in a dataframe or export straight to a csv (whichever gets me the data in one place).

Doesn't necessarily have to be done using pandas.

What I've tried so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql

from datetime import date
dates = [
    date(year=2016, month=1, day=12), 
    date(year=2016, month=1, day=13),
    date(year=2016, month=1, day=14),
]

conn = pymysql.connect(...)
cursor = conn.cursor()

frame = []
for date in dates:
    query = """SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = {date}""".format(date=date)
    cursor.execute(query)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(data))
    frame.append(df)
conn.close()
```

Alternatively tried something like the following for the dates:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

start = date(2015, 9, 9)
end = date.today()
week = timedelta(days=7)

mydate = start
while mydate < end:
    print("{date.day:02}{date.month:02}{date.year}".format(date=mydate))
    mydate += week
```

Trouble I'm having is piecing everything together properly and making it work...
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to query your db and return the result set as a `pandas.DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql

from datetime import date

dates = [
    date(year=2016, month=1, day=12), 
    date(year=2016, month=1, day=13),
    date(year=2016, month=1, day=14),
]

conn = pymysql.connect(...)

query = """SELECT * FROM table WHERE date IN ({})""".format(','.join(dates))

df = pd.read_sql(query, con=conn)

conn.close()
```

`pandas` has a built in method for utilizing your db connection to perform and return queries as `pd.DataFrame` structures. You can then run `df.to_csv` to export your results. In the `query` variable, remember that it's a `str` type so it's a matter of formatting your query properly with a little help from python, which is what we use the `','.join(dates)` for which will return your list elements in a string, separated by commas. Keep in mind you may need to convert your dates to match whatever date format exists within your db.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - the problem is that the table I'm querying is over 100 million rows for 1-2 years worth of data. What I was thinking of doing is querying a day's worth (which can be queried fine), appending that to an empty dataframe and then the next day's and so on so forth. Which is why I'm sure a for/while loop would do the trick?

Comment: If that's the case then you can loop over subsets and merge them at the end. So, `df_list = []` and `df_list.append(df)` for each subset frame, then you can concatenate them at the end using `pd.concat(df_list, axis=0)` or store them as separate files.